# I`m Trying To Merge Two Adapter In One Recycler View but when Irun my app the app will be crashed

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, adapter

[Here is the logcat error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITDXk.png)
**I face some crash issue in my app when I run the app will be crashed, I`m doing two adapter merger in one recycler view at loading time app will be crashed I don't know about why app will be crashed**

I`m Using Latest Recycler view Dependency of androidx :-     implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha02'

logcat error

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sti/com.example.sti.testing_activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.hasStableIds()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3735)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3903)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2328)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.hasStableIds()' on a null object reference
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.MergeAdapterController.addAdapter(MergeAdapterController.java:151)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.MergeAdapterController.addAdapter(MergeAdapterController.java:132)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.MergeAdapter.addAdapter(MergeAdapter.java:142)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.MergeAdapter.<init>(MergeAdapter.java:125)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.MergeAdapter.<init>(MergeAdapter.java:101)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.MergeAdapter.<init>(MergeAdapter.java:87)
        at com.example.sti.testing_activity.merger(testing_activity.java:77)
        at com.example.sti.testing_activity.onCreate(testing_activity.java:62)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8151)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8135)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3704)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3903) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2328) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049) 
2021-11-20 16:01:24.101 784-790/? E/statsd: Predicate 5980654721335871649 dropping data for dimension key (10)0x2010101->10646[I] (10)0x30000->*launch*[S] 
2021-11-20 16:01:24.139 2498-2498/? E/Launcher.ColorBubbleTextView: mForceHideDot is false
2021-11-20 16:01:24.140 2498-2498/? E/Launcher.ColorBubbleTextView: mForceHideDot is false
2021-11-20 16:01:24.140 2498-2498/? E/Launcher.ColorBubbleTextView: mForceHideDot is false
2021-11-20 16:01:24.140 2498-2498/? E/Launcher.ColorBubbleTextView: mForceHideDot is false
2021-11-20 16:01:24.163 2498-2498/? E/Launcher.ColorBubbleTextView: mForceHideDot is false
2021-11-20 16:01:24.163 2498-2498/? E/Launcher.ColorBubbleTextView: mForceHideDot is false
2021-11-20 16:01:24.164 2498-2498/? E/Launcher.ColorBubbleTextView: mForceHideDot is false
2021-11-20 16:01:24.164 2498-2498/? E/Launcher.ColorBubbleTextView: mForceHideDot is false
2021-11-20 16:01:24.165 2498-2498/? E/Launcher.ColorBubbleTextView: mForceHideDot is false
2021-11-20 16:01:24.211 784-790/? E/statsd: Predicate 5980654721335871649 dropping data for dimension key (10)0x2010101->10166[I] (10)0x30000->CMWakeLock[S] 
2021-11-20 16:01:24.227 784-790/? E/statsd: Predicate 5980654721335871649 dropping data for dimension key (10)0x2010101->10166[I] (10)0x30000->CMWakeLock[S] 
2021-11-20 16:01:24.296 2498-2498/? E/Launcher.ColorBubbleTextView: mForceHideDot is false
2021-11-20 16:01:24.470 2461-2461/? E/OplusNecManagerHelper: com.oplus.nec.OplusNecManager.notifyOrigSignalStrengthChanged [class android.telephony.SignalStrength, int]
2021-11-20 16:01:24.556 845-917/? E/UxUtility: notifyAppState error = NULL
2021-11-20 16:01:24.577 3243-1764/? E/oiface: packageSwitch pkg com.oppo.launcher, enter
2021-11-20 16:01:24.578 3243-1764/? E/oiface: current package is com.oppo.launcher and pid is 2498
2021-11-20 16:01:24.585 3243-3256/? E/oiface: Average freq 1144275 for 12s.
2021-11-20 16:01:24.586 3243-3256/? E/oiface: Average freq 1265076 for 12s.
2021-11-20 16:01:24.586 3243-3256/? E/oiface: get gpu config path failed. Fallback to default.
2021-11-20 16:01:24.586 1653-1666/? E/ORMS_Platform : OplusResourceManagerPlatformUtils: readFile function exception:/sys/devices/platform/soc/5000000.qcom,kgsl-3d0/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/freq_table_mhz: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-11-20 16:01:24.586 3243-3256/? E/oiface: get gpu freq table failed
2021-11-20 16:01:24.589 3243-3256/? E/oiface: client  not found, skipped
2021-11-20 16:01:24.594 3243-3256/? E/oiface: get gpu config path failed. Fallback to default.
2021-11-20 16:01:24.595 1653-4015/? E/ORMS_Platform : OplusResourceManagerPlatformUtils: readFile function exception:/sys/devices/platform/soc/5000000.qcom,kgsl-3d0/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/freq_table_mhz: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-11-20 16:01:24.595 3243-3256/? E/oiface: get gpu freq table failed
2021-11-20 16:01:27.040 2461-2461/? E/OplusNecManagerHelper: com.oplus.nec.OplusNecManager.notifyOrigSignalStrengthChanged [class android.telephony.SignalStrength, int]
2021-11-20 16:01:28.304 25110-25139/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
2021-11-20 16:01:29.374 3239-3251/? E/horae: 0: back:36418,frame:34468,front:35954, 6, +(2982), 1 ,36200,40000,39400,39200
2021-11-20 16:01:29.600 2461-2461/? E/OplusNecManagerHelper: com.oplus.nec.OplusNecManager.notifyOrigSignalStrengthChanged [class android.telephony.SignalStrength, int]
2021-11-20 16:01:30.035 5321-5337/? E/IHansComunication: HANS printMessageBody: RCVed message body: type = 0, port = 86870, caller_pid = 1653, caller_uid = 1000, target_pid = 15035, target_uid = 10266, pkg_cmd = -1
2021-11-20 16:01:32.159 2461-2461/? E/OplusNecManagerHelper: com.oplus.nec.OplusNecManager.notifyOrigSignalStrengthChanged [class android.telephony.SignalStrength, int]
2021-11-20 16:01:34.075 3243-1764/? E/oiface: Abnormal! com.oppo.launcher[com.oppo.launcher/com.oppo.launcher.Launcher#0] current fps is: 0.000000 abnormal, return 0
2021-11-20 16:01:34.721 2461-2461/? E/OplusNecManagerHelper: com.oplus.nec.OplusNecManager.notifyOrigSignalStrengthChanged [class android.telephony.SignalStrength, int]
2021-11-20 16:01:37.278 2461-2461/? E/OplusNecManagerHelper: com.oplus.nec.OplusNecManager.notifyOrigSignalStrengthChanged [class android.telephony.SignalStrength, int]
2021-11-20 16:01:39.076 3243-1764/? E/oiface: Abnormal! com.oppo.launcher[com.oppo.launcher/com.oppo.launcher.Launcher#0] current fps is: 0.000000 abnormal, return 0
2021-11-20 16:01:39.839 2461-2461/? E/OplusNecManagerHelper: com.oplus.nec.OplusNecManager.notifyOrigSignalStrengthChanged [class android.telephony.SignalStrength, int]
2021-11-20 16:01:41.994 25217-25217/? E/com.truecaller: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x40000000
2021-11-20 16:01:42.001 25217-25217/? E/com.truecaller: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2021-11-20 16:01:42.009 25217-25217/? E/RefClass: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2021-11-20 16:01:42.187 25217-25242/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
2021-11-20 16:01:42.205 25217-25244/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
2021-11-20 16:01:42.512 550-560/? E/cutils: Failed to fstatat(/mnt/media_rw/7C80-0817/Android/data/com.truecaller/cache): I/O error
2021-11-20 16:01:42.583 25217-25276/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
2021-11-20 16:01:42.608 25217-25244/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
```

here is my code .

coureseadapter_re.java

```
public class coureseadapter_re extends RecyclerView.Adapter<coureseadapter_re.coureseviewholder> {


    private ArrayList<courseinfo.Blog>blogs;
    private Context context;
  


    public coureseadapter_re(ArrayList<courseinfo.Blog> blogs, Context context) {
        this.blogs = blogs;
        this.context = context;

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public coureseviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater li=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        return  new coureseviewholder(CoureseinfoBinding.inflate(li));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull coureseviewholder holder, int position) {
        holder.binding.pointN.setText(blogs.get(position).getPoint());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return blogs.size();
    }

    class coureseviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        CoureseinfoBinding binding;
        coureseviewholder(CoureseinfoBinding c){
            super(c.getRoot());
            binding=c;
        }
    }

}
```

spinneradapter_re.java

```
public class spinneradapter_re extends RecyclerView.Adapter<spinneradapter_re.getdeloperholder>{

    private ArrayList<com.example.sti.Models.getdeveloper.Developer> getdevelopers;
    private Context context;
    private getdeveloper deve;



    private ArrayList<String>developerid=new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String>developername=new ArrayList<>();



    public spinneradapter_re(ArrayList<com.example.sti.Models.getdeveloper.Developer> getdevelopers, Context context) {
        this.getdevelopers=getdevelopers;
        this.context=context;

        developername.add("Select faculty");
        for (int i=0;i<getdevelopers.size();i++){
            developername.add(getdevelopers.get(i).getName());
            developerid.add(getdevelopers.get(i).getId());
        }

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public getdeloperholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater l1=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        return new getdeloperholder(ReSpinnerBinding.inflate(l1));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull getdeloperholder holder, int position) {

        ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String> (context,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,developername);
        adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        holder.binding.facN.setAdapter(adp);
        holder.binding.facN.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MaterialSpinner.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(MaterialSpinner view, int position, long id, Object item) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return getdevelopers.size();
    }

    class getdeloperholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ReSpinnerBinding binding;
        getdeloperholder(ReSpinnerBinding b){
            super(b.getRoot());
            binding=b;
        }
    }
}
```

testing_activity.java

```
public class testing_activity extends AppCompatActivity {



    ActivityTestingBinding binding;
    ApiInterface apiInterface;
    private com.example.sti.utils.progresshandler progresshandler;
    private Context context;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    coureseadapter_re re;
    spinneradapter_re spinneradapter_re;
    ArrayList<coureseadapter_re> coureseadapter_res;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding=ActivityTestingBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        apiInterface= ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        progresshandler=new progresshandler(this);


        merger();
        processing();
        spinnerPorcess();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        binding=null;
    }

    void merger(){

        MergeAdapter mergeAdapter=new MergeAdapter(re,spinneradapter_re);
        binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(mergeAdapter);
    }


    public void processing(){
        progresshandler.show();
        Call<courseinfo> call=apiInterface.getdetails(getIntent().getExtras().getString("id"));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<courseinfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<courseinfo> call, Response<courseinfo> response) {
                courseinfo courseinfo= response.body();
                Log.i("response",courseinfo.getStatus());
                first_adapter(response.body().getBlogs());
                progresshandler.hide();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<courseinfo> call, Throwable t) {
                progresshandler.hide();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }



    public void spinnerPorcess(){
        progresshandler.show();
        Call<getdeveloper>call=apiInterface.getdeve(getIntent().getExtras().getString("id"));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<getdeveloper>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<getdeveloper> call, Response<getdeveloper> response) {
                getdeveloper getdeveloper=response.body();
                if(response.body()!=null){
                    Log.i("responsepspin",getdeveloper.getStatus());
                    second_adapter(response.body().getDeveloper());
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<getdeveloper> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }



    public void  first_adapter(ArrayList<courseinfo.Blog>blogs){
        re=new coureseadapter_re(blogs,testing_activity.this);
    }

    private void second_adapter(ArrayList<getdeveloper.Developer>developers){
        spinneradapter_re=new spinneradapter_re(developers,testing_activity.this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the logcat error when the app crashes.

Comment: @AbhishekDutt hi I Attached my logcat error please if you know about this solution of this error so give me proper solution to find accurate output.. thanks in adavance.

Comment: have you got any answer for this. i am facing same issue.

Comment: you can use ConcatAdapter to join few adapters